# Safari wrapping too early

Tags: css, safari

I've created a class web page with a page for midterm review.  It uses jsMath to turn Tex into nice math.  (MathML looks awful)  Anyway, I would occasionally like to have several problems per line.  Each problem is in its own `<span>`, so if it needs to wrap, it won't split the problem.

It all seems to work, except that Safari for the Mac seems overly anxious to wrap, sometimes wrapping at 30% paragraph width.  Even under inspection, it reports a width of 663px, but wrapping occurs at around 150px.  There is no padding.

Firefox renders just fine.  A comparison is here: http://davehampson.net/Images/Safaribug.png Sometimes Safari works just fine.

The original web page is here:  http://math.davehampson.net/index3.php (study guide 2)

I don't know if this is a bug in safari, or if there is some odd/subtle css point I am missing.  Any help would be appreciated.

--Dave

Answer (score 0):

You are using **"cm"** for your margin? Did you mean to use **"em"**?

Comment: I planned on a 1 cm gap.  It doesn't matter what I make it though, it still wraps too soon.